# ogr2ogr: filter on date-field

Tags: ogr, filter, date

ogr2ogr -spat_srs EPSG:31370 -spat 179600 167350 179800 167500 -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp "WFS:http://ccff02.minfin.fgov.be/geoservices/arcgis/services/WMS/Cadastral_Layers/MapServer/WFSServer?" Cadastral_parcel

There is also a date field in this WFS-web service [LasUpdDTS].
Is it possible to filter on this field: between 2018/05/01 and 2018/08/01
I suppose it is possible with -sql option?

Comment: Is the time string "YYYY/MM/DD" or "YYYY/DD/MM"? Actually I can see that in the data it is is ISO format `LastUpdDTS>2016-09-29T22:48:52</CL:LastUpdDTS`  http://ccff02.minfin.fgov.be/geoservices/arcgis/services/WMS/Cadastral_Layers/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&TypeName=Cadastral_parcel&count=1

Comment: ogr2ogr -where "LastUpdDTS>'2016-09-29T22:48:52'" -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp "WFS:http://ccff02.minfin.fgov.be/geoservices/arcgis/services/WMS/Cadastral_Layers/MapServer/WFSServer?" Cadastral_parcel

This command doesn't work...
ERROR 1 : Error returned by server : <ows:ExceptionReport version= '1.1.10' language='en' xmlns:ows='http://www.opengis.net/ows'></ows:ExceptionReport>

Comment: If you turn debug on with `--debug on` you can see that GDAL makes this request `http://ccff02.minfin.fgov.be/geoservices/arcgis/services/WMS/Cadastral_Layers/MapServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=CL:Cadastral_parcel&FILTER=<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><PropertyIsGreaterThan><PropertyName>LastUpdDTS</PropertyName><Literal>2016-09-29T22:48:52</Literal></PropertyIsGreaterThan></Filter>` Hopefully you can find out why it does not work.